# How to know what's inside of the result returned by $cordovaSQLite.execute

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sqlite

See, for example, this snippet from the `http://ngcordova.com/` site:

```
$scope.execute = function() {
var query = "INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test", 100]).then(function(res) {
  console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
}, function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

};

He prints `res.insertId`, but does he know the atribute is called insertId? Where can I check that. I want to see if there's an atribute inside res with the executed command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Prints the object and all it's properties

Answer (score 2):

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test", 100]).then(function(res) {
console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(res.rows.item(i));
}
}
```

try this (y)